Minimize Expenses For Workers
My goal is to minimize the labor expenses. Say we have 3 types of workers:
$x_1$ = Permanent Driver, rate = 693.875/day
$x_2$ = Reliever Drivers rate = 435/day
$x_3$ = Crews rate = 400/day
There are 6 trucks to operate, 1 driver and 4 crews each. In a week, (Mon.-Sun.), $x_1$ and $x_3$ should only work 5 days then reliever drivers and other crews must step in. Current number of hired personnel are $x_1=6, x_2=4$, and $x_3=40$.
With this, in a week, there must be 6 of $x_1$, at least 2 of $x_2$, and at least 24 crews.
I did make a table but I got lost. I tried to make it $X_{itd}$ where $i=(1,2,3), t=(1,2,...,6)$, and $d=(1,2,...,7)$. So I ended up with 126 variables, I guess. So I really don't know how to formulate and solve it. Is there somehow an easier way to minimize these?

You said x1 should only work 5 days, and number of x1 is 6. So, did you mean that every permanent drivers can only work 5 days in a week? or all of them in total only work 5 days?

@ytsao, what i meant was each of them (permanent drivers) can only work 5 days per week.

So, could they work under 5 days per week? Also, what's the rate meaning? is there any demand must be satisfied in the problem?

Have $i$ be the set of days where $i=\{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun\}$. Additionally, let $j$ denote the quantity of drivers with $j=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, have $k$ denote the range of workers where $k=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $l$ be the range of crew where $l=\{1,2,3,\ldots,39,40\}$.
Thus, let $D_{ij}$ be a binary variable denoting the usage of drivers, $R_{ik}$ be a binary variable denoting the usage of relief drivers, and $C_{il}$ be a binary variable the usage of representing crew - where the decision variable equals one if a driver/relief/crew of a certain type are used on a certain day, zero otherwise. Therefore, we are trying to optimize the following:
$$
\begin{array}{llc}
\min z= & 693.875\sum_i\sum_jD_{ij} + 435\sum_i\sum_kR_{ik}+400\sum_i\sum_l C_{il}&\\
s.t.& \sum\limits_jD_{ij} + \sum\limits_kR_{ik}=6\quad\forall i&\text{(All Trucks are Driven)}\\
& \sum\limits_lC_{il}=24\quad\forall i&\text{(All Trucks have Crew)}\\
&\sum\limits_iD_{ij}\le 5q_{1j}\quad\forall j&\text{(Driver 5 day limit)}\\
&\sum\limits_iC_{il}\le 5q_{2l}\quad\forall l&\text{(Crew 5 day limit)}\\
&\sum\limits_kR_{ik}\le 7q_{3k}\quad\forall k&\text{(Relief measuring)}\\
&\sum\limits_jq_{1j}\ge 6&\text{(Drivers Minimum)}\\
&\sum\limits_lq_{2l}\ge 24&\text{(Crew Minimum)}\\
&\sum\limits_kq_{3k}\ge 2&\text{(Relief Minimum)}\\
&D_{ij},R_{ik},C_{il},q_{1j},q_{2l},q_{3k}\in\{0,1\}\quad\forall i,j,k,l& \text{(Binary assertion)}
\end{array}$$
where $q_{1j},q_{2l},q_{3k}$ are binary decision variables that measure if a driver/relief/crew is being used in the whole week.

If Crew/Drivers must work exactly five days, then the Drivers/Crew limit constraints can be changed to equality
